# Error generating Ubuntu 12.04 with live build

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to build an Ubuntu image using live build:

```
lb config --mode ubuntu --distribution precise --debian-installer true --debian-installer true --debian-installer-gui true
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Reading state information...
Package busybox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  busybox-static:i386 busybox-static

E: Package 'busybox' has no installation candidate
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
```

Answer (score 3):

live-builder defaults to only using the "main" component when building its chroots. This is fine for Debian, where all the packages needed to install a base system are present in main.  Unfortunately, Ubuntu has put busybox in "universe", so you will need to add `--archive-areas "main universe"` and possibly also `--parent-archive-areas "main universe"` to your lb config invocation in order to find it.

Answer (score 0):

install then these two for build as mentioned over there.
Just open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install busybox-static:i386 busybox-static
```

Comment: Not if you used live build but gives an error when you remove the generated file system and exits the construction of the image.